# How to show action bar icons's on a fragment?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm using a navigation drawer for my application which includes fragments. I'm also using an action icon. But when I use the drawer to change activities, the action icon is on all the activities. I only want it on one of the fragments. This is my code

```
package com.colourity.snatsh;

import com.colourity.snatsh.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.colourity.snatsh.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import com.colourity.snatsh.model.NavDrawerItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to work when I  try it in my `HomeFragment`. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems)'s the guide I'm using.

**EDIT:**

I get the following errors while trying the guide in my `HomeFragment`

`The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater) in the type Fragment is not applicable for the arguments (Menu) HomeFragment.java   /Snatsh/src/com/colourity/snatsh    line 29 Java Problem`

`The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type HomeFragment    HomeFragment.java   /Snatsh/src/com/colourity/snatsh    line 27 Java Problem`

`The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type HomeFragment must override or implement a supertype method    HomeFragment.java   /Snatsh/src/com/colourity/snatsh    line 25 Java Problem`

Comment: its an action bar thing... you can't have it for one activity and not for the other.

Comment: Then how does Kik do it? http://imgur.com/jIdhlBu,FzOhJzN#0 

http://imgur.com/jIdhlBu,FzOhJzN#1

I'm sure it's possible @user2511882

Comment: ohh you mean different icons?

Comment: Yes. I've, sorry for the confusion. I've edited my title @user2511882

Comment: what is the problem you are getting?

Comment: Error's posted above. @user2511882

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onCreateOptionsMenu` is missing a parameter, try this instead:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
}
```

and add the additional import (if not done automatically):

```
import android.view.MenuInflater;
```

Comment: I get two errors. 

`The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater) in the type Fragment is not applicable for the arguments (Menu)` 
And
`The return type is incompatible with Fragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater)`

Comment: I changed my code, actually this function does not have a boolean in return. It should return nothing on a `Fragment`.

Comment: Thanks so far. Now I get no errors, but the icon doesn't show up.

Comment: This button belongs to the main menu? How many menus do you have? You can create a separate one only displayed on the fragments.

Comment: I'm using a navigation drawer. And I have 4 activates/fragments for it. I have 1 menu since i'm still working on it.  The menu is called `main`.

Comment: You need specific action buttons for every fragment?

Comment: I just made 4 new menus. All include `<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_new"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
          android:title="@null"
          android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>`. And then I put your code in and change the `R.menu.NAME, menu);`. But it still doesn't show

Comment: Be careful also to the order, by default it will be added to the main menu buttons. your new button might only be visible using the menu button.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. But I correctly named them and changed the ID's, but nothing changes.

Comment: No buttons at all? Even from main? I am not sure how to help you, you should explain what buttons you have in the main activity (if there are any) and what buttons you have in your fragments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48174/discussion-between-user3342131-and-yoann-hercouet)